# How to write helper method for presenting collection in tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, helper

I want to add helper for presenting my tasks in tabs.

```
module Users::TasksHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def present_in_tabs collection
    content_tag :div, class: "tabbable tabs-left" do
      content_tag :ul, class: 'nav nav-tabs' do
        collection.collect do |item|
          content_tag :li do
            link_to "Zadanie #{1}", "#task-#{item.id}", data: { toggle: 'tab' }
          end
        end.join.html_safe
      end

      content_tag :div, class: 'tab-content' do
        collection.collect do |item|
          content_tag :div, class: 'tab-pane' do
            concat content_tag :h3 do
              item.name
            end
            content_tag :p do
              item.description
            end
          end
        end.join.html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I want to convert to helper method

```
.tabbable.tabs-left
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs
    - @related_tasks.each_with_index do |task, i|
      %li{class: if task == @current_task then 'active' end}
        = link_to "Zadanie #{i+1}", "#task-#{task.id}", data: { toggle: 'tab' }

  .tab-content
    - @related_tasks.each do |task|
      .tab-pane{id: "task-#{task.id}", class: if task == @current_task then 'active' end}
        %h3= task.name
        %p
          = task.description
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: why you wanna to convert this to a helper method but not using a partial?

Comment: You can simply emplement it through partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is fairly trivial:

```
        concat content_tag :h3 do
          item.name
        end
        content_tag :p do
          item.description
        end
```

You are mixing concat and returning values. You need to make sure to use `concat` OR returning a string from a helper. Have a look at the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat

So a helper used with `<%= %>` needs to create one `html_safe` string, while you could also a helper with `concat` within `<% %>`.

A better solution would be to use a partial, like @cenyongh pointed out.